# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 5), found shape=(None, 5)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I've split my dataset into X_train and y_train dataframes with respective shapes of (371,5) and (371,) and I can't understand why I keep getting the above error. Code is below:

`

```
import tensorflow as tf #machine learning
from sklearn import metrics

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, 5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

`

I don't understand how to make it a valid input to a Sequential layer, I've tried solutions from previous posts such as using `X_train[1]` as an argument in `model.fit` to no avail.

Comment: `input_shape` should probably be `(5)`, not `(1, 5)`. Neither of your shapes even have non-last dimension size 1.

Comment: Following on the comment of @DJinn --- `input_shape=(5,)` should work (note the comma after 5).